# Decimal to Binary in Rust

Tags: beginner, rust, number-systems

As a beginner in Rust i am trying to practice Rust with some little programs
so here is my implementation of Decimal to Binary.

```
use std::io;

pub fn run() {
    let number = input("Enter an input");
    println!("{}", to_binary(number));
}

fn input(msg: &str) -> i32 {
    println!("{}", msg);
    let mut number = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut number)
        .expect("Failed to read input");

    match number.trim().parse() {
        Ok(num) => num,
        Err(_e) => panic!("Not a number"),
    }
}

fn to_binary(mut decimal: i32) -> i32 {
    if decimal == 0 {
        decimal
    } else {
        let mut bits = String::new();

        while decimal > 0 {
            if decimal % 2 == 0 {
                bits.push_str("0");
            } else {
                bits.push_str("1");
            }

            decimal /= 2;
        }

        // reverse the bits
        match bits.chars().rev().collect::<String>().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_e) => panic!("Something went wrong"),
        }
    }
}
```

so feel free to advice anything you consider.
i just have three questions in particular

1. isn't it better to write `input` as a macro ?
2. how can i write `to_binary` as pure function ?
3. wouldn't be better to return binary type from `to_binary` instead i32

Comment: Just to make sure: when you say you're a "beginner in Rust", are you also a beginner in general programming, or do you have previous programming experience?

Comment: i have a little experience in general programing

Answer (score 7):

> isn't it better to write input as a macro ?

No. At best it might work as a generic function.

> how can i write to_binary as pure function ?

It already is a pure function, it doesn't mutate or depend on external state

> wouldn't be better to return binary type from to_binary instead i32

You should return a `String`. Converting to i32 is pretty weird. The numbers inside i32 are already in binary. The point of a to_binary function is pretty much always because you for some reason want a textual representation in binary.

As a quick side note, Rust already has the ability to convert values to binary:

```
format!("{:b}", value);
```

Your to_binary function would be a bit simpler if build a Vec or Vec  and then converted that instead of building a String.